# Windows CE 6.0 - Spinning Hourglass

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

How do you remove the spinning hourglass that runs during application loading on Windows CE 6.0.  Here is a screenshot of the hourglass:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this link that shows how to do this:

http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/1695088/

It is just a hidden registry entry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / System / GWE]
"DelayCursorTimerQuantum" = dword: ffffffff
```